# Is the operator identity $[X,F(P)]=[X,P]F'(P)$ always true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, commutator

I came up with the operator identity in my QM textbook

$$
[X,F(P)]=[X,P]F'(P)
$$

where $X,P$ are Hermitian operators whose commutator commutes with them: $$[X,[X,P]]=[P,[X,P]]=0.$$ $F(x)$ is some well-behaved function.

In the book, the identity is proved by verifying $$[X,P^n]=[X,P]nP^{n-1}$$ by induction and then expanding $F(x)$ into power series. However, the identity still works under conditions where this is quite impossible. For example,
$$
[X,P^{-2}]=-2[X,P]P^{-3}\\
[X,\sqrt P]=\frac12[X,P]P^{-1/2}
$$

is also true at least in some cases. (the second identity requires $P$ to be positive) As for the position and momentum case, it is beyond doubt because in the $p$-representation $X$ is $i\hbar\dfrac{d}{dp}$ and the identities are obvious. But difficulties occur when the commutator is not a constant.

**Question** Can we prove the identity is indeed true in such cases, or are they actually not true and there are some more restrictions on the function $F(x)$?

Comment: If the commutator of X with P is not a constant, the identity fails. Try a simple example.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Could you please provide an example? I think the argument for usual functions is sufficient.

Comment: Why would you even expect this to hold in cases where the commutator is not constant? Why would you call the operators $X$ and $P$ if their commutation relations are not the canonical ones?

Answer (score 1):

As it finally emerges from your graduated comments, you certainly ought to have indicated that your Hilbert space goes beyond the image of all functions of *X* and *P*! In the language of the field, this center  *Y* is a "constant", to the extent *X* and *P* commutations don't affect it.   You need not fuss with weird operators: Indeed, the identity holds for the simplest [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#The_three-dimensional_case), trivially. But, in physics, a "constant" is an element of the center of the Lie algebra!

In any case, your operators
$$
X=e^{-i\phi} (-\partial_\theta + i \cot \theta ~ \partial_\phi), \qquad P=\cos\theta ,\\
\leadsto ~~~~ [X,P]\equiv Y =e^{-\phi} \sin\theta , \leadsto [Y,X]=[Y,P]=0,
$$
do satisfy the identity, for *F* Laurent-expandible, avoiding the singularities inherent in the weird operators you chose (take θ small avoiding 0). Many operator identities of this form parallel similar [Sylvester's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula) identities for matrices.

Comment: It's stated that $X$ and $P$ commute with their commutator $[X,P]$, while your example certainly violates the condition since $[P,[X,P]]=[P,X]=-X\ne0$.

Comment: But, if they ***both*** commuted with their commutator, the commutator would be a constant,  wouldn't it? That's what a constant is. Isn't this your question?

Comment: Whether your statement is true, it does not seem obvious to me. Could you provide a precise proof?

Comment: You might rewrite your question then, to be asking about just this. Informally, an operator commuting with all noncommuting operators on  the conventional  Hilbert space is a constant times the identity. There is no other center.

Comment: Are you working in the 3x3 matrix realization of the Heisenberg group? What "difficulties" are you encountering?

Comment: 1. The condition of the commutators is stated in the first place.  2. There are indeed examples out there. Let $L_-=L_1-i L_2$ be one of the laddar operators of orbital angular momentum, $N_0$ be one of the components of the direction operator that points at the $z$ axis, which is $\cos\theta$ in coordinate representation, and $Y$ be the operator who is $e^{-i\varphi}\sin\theta$ in coordinate representation. Then it can be shown that $[L_-,N_0]=\hbar Y, [Y,L_-]=[Y,N_0]=0$, which agrees with my conditon while $Y$ is certainly not a constant.

Comment: The commutator does not have to commute with all other noncommuting operators. It just need to commute with $X$ and $P$, as stated.